# How to cross-classify two categorical variables?

Tags: r, classification, categorical-data

I have a data frame with two categorical variables (representing different methods) that "classify" objects into three categories: `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`. The objects are classified somewhat differently by the two variables and I would like to perform a test described as "Measuring Agreement Between Observers" in Agresti's CDA, Section 10.5 (after Thompson 2009, p. 192) to check if both methods perform differently.

Wanting to follow the example in package exactLoglinTest, I struggle to create a cross-classification data frame similar to `library(exactLoglinTest); data(pathologist.dat)`

My variables are in the following form:

```
classification.1    classification.2
cat1                cat1
cat1                cat2
cat3                cat3
cat2                cat2
cat2                cat3
```

...etc

I have more than thousand classified observations and (as far as I understand) I would like to count all the combinations - i.e. `cat1` & `cat1`, `cat1` & `cat2`, `cat1` & `cat3`, etc.

How can I achieve this?

References: Thompson, L.A. 2009. R (and S-PLUS) Manual to Accompany Agresti’s Categorical Data Analysis (2002) 2nd edition. [available online](https://home.comcast.net/~lthompson221/Splusdiscrete2.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried `table(classification.1, classification.2)` or `xtable`?

Comment: Yes, Henrik, but this way I get a table and not the needed long data frame.

Comment: @ils, once you have a table, you can coerce it to a data.frame (`as.data.frame(table(your.object))`). Try it and see if the output is what you are after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fakeData <- data.frame(var1 = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, TRUE)
                       , var2 = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, TRUE))

yourTable <- with(fakeData, table(var1, var2))

#Option 1
as.data.frame(yourTable)
#Option 2
require(reshape2)
melt(yourTable)
```

Gives you something like:

```
  var1 var2 Freq
1    a    a  107
2    b    a  116
3    c    a  119
4    a    b  109
5    b    b  109
6    c    b  106
7    a    c  100
8    b    c  121
9    c    c  113
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all hints! The ```as.data.frame``` command was the one I was largely missing. Being aware of it now is *cool* :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want counts of how many instances of each combination of classifications you have, I think @Henrik's suggestion will do that for you.  On the other hand, if what you want is to rearrange your data frame into the 'long' form, take a look at [?reshape](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html).  You may also be interested in the [reshape](http://had.co.nz/reshape/) [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/index.html).  Quick-R has a, er, quick overview of [it](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you, @gung! I still cannot grok reshape, but feeling that it is very powerful I'll have to look more closer at it.